# Play: How to prevent the body parser from being invoked in case the action code does not get executed

Tags: scala, playframework

I've created a custom `Action` that prevents unauthorized users from accessing protected functionality:

```
class SecureAction extends ActionBuilder[SecureRequest] {

  def invokeBlock[A](request: Request[A], block: SecureRequest[A] => Future[Result]) = {
    ...
    future.flatMap {
      case token if (!isAuthorized(token)) =>
        Logger.info(s"request ${request.path} not authorized: user ${token.username} does not have required privileges")
        Future.successful(Unauthorized(error(requestNotAuthorized))))
      case ...
    }
  }
}
```

If the current user is not authorized, then `SecureAction` returns `Unauthorized` and never executes the provided action code. Below is how my `Controller` looks like:

```
object MyController extends Controller {

  ...

  def saveFile = SecureAction.async(fsBodyParser) { implicit request =>

    // code here not executed if current user has not required privileges
    ...
  }
}
```

The problem is that even if the current user is not authorized and `SecureAction` returns `Unauthorized` without executing the action code, the body parser gets still invoked... and this is not what I was expecting.

That said, the question is: how do I prevent the body parser (i.e `fsBodyParser`) from being invoked in case `SecureAction` returns `Unauthorized`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at EssentialAction (https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/api/scala/index.html#play.api.mvc.EssentialAction)

As you can see, this is the definition of EssentialAction:

```
trait EssentialAction extends (RequestHeader) ⇒ Iteratee[Array[Byte], SimpleResult] with Handler
```

So, if you want to operate at the request header level, prefer EssentialActions. Unlike Action/ActionBuilders they don't need interaction with BodyParsers.

It's worth mentioning this awesome post by @marius-soutier: http://mariussoutier.com/blog/2013/09/17/playframework-2-2-action-building-action-composition/